# Failed to edit my Admin Panel on Server using wordpress ?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

i am using wordpress and php to build my site but the problem is that i have moved my whole website on Server andnow i want to change header image of my site i can edit the admin panel in localhost and have successfully changed my header image and its working fine in Localhost and have updated my database to Server as well but header image is not displaying on Server and also i am unable to edit my "ADMIN PANEL"  on Server userId and password is fine but on click of any sidebar links its doing nothing can someone please help me.

[Server Admin Link](http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/AlFerdous/admin/wp-admin/edit.php)

[Server Website](http://demo.ingresssolutions.com/AlFerdous/admin/user-login/)

can someone please help me how can i edit my admin panel of server so that i can change my header image on server

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your database when you moved your website that the siteurl and home in wp_options is now correct to the new url? If you are just uploading your localhost database every time these (and other links) may now be wrong?

Comment: yes i have changed my database in wp_options this now repsresents new url but it still not working  can u please help me

Comment: Have you upgraded to 3.8.2? If your sidebar links are not working in the dashboard (check they are not linking to /localhost/ still) try re-uploading a fresh install of the wp-admin / wp-includes and root files (not wp-config.php though) and see if that clears it up.